# How to search for files in sd card with some keyword?

Tags: android

I am making an app which creates a back up of data in excel sheet with filename followed by current date like "myfile_01-01-2014" and "myfile_01-15-2014" and so on... you can see the date is variable. I want to search for the keyword "myfile_" so that I can get a list of files according to date created. and I want to use the latest file for restore purpose.

```
(Is it possieble)? "How" : "tell me any other way to do this";
```

thank you...

Comment: like u want to all files which contain "myfile_" is it u want

Comment: yes! but in a specified folder

Comment: ohk see my answer and just put your specified folder name with attribute of method where i put Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() this instead of this just pass your specified folder address/path

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To search files with  a string keyword use the following function,

```
public ArrayList<File> searchFile(File parent,final String searchKeyWord) {
    ArrayList<File> result = new ArrayList<File>();
    File[] files = parent.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File dir, String filename) {
            return filename.contains(searchKeyWord);
        }
    });
    for (File file : files) {
        result.add(file);
    }
    return result;
}
```

For more filtering options change the below line with string opertations like `startsWith` `endWith` etc..

```
 return filename.contains(searchKeyWord);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursive searching. Use this function with path of directory where you wanna start search your files (for example "/mnt/sdcard").

```
public Vector<String> yourFiles = new Vector<String>();

private void searchInDirectory(String directory)
{
File dir = new File(directory);

if(dir.canRead() && dir.exists() && dir.isDirectory())
{
    String []filesInDirectory = dir.list();
    if(filesInDirectory != null)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<filesInDirectory.length; i++)
        {

            File file = new File(directory+"/"+filesInDirectory[i]);                    

            if(file.isFile() && filesInDirectory[i].startsWith("myfile"))
            {
                yourFiles.add(directory+"/"+filesInDirectory[i]);
            }
            else if(file.isDirectory() )
            {
                searchInDirectory(file.getAbsolutePath());
            }

        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this dude

call this method like

```
getAllDocument(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
```

and method diff is...

```
public void getAllDocument(File dir) {
            File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();

            if (listFile != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {

                    if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
                        getAllDocument(listFile[i]);
                    } else {


                            listFile[i].getName();
                            if(!listFile[i].getAbsolutePath().startsWith("myfile_"))
                            { 

                                //took this file into your wraaper or then just comapre for the newest with your logic
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: ok Bhanu can you tell me what will be the order of the file in array listFile

Comment: every file contain its last modify date dude  :::::   Date lastModified = new Date(file.lastModified()); it will give u date of that file just match with ur need dude

Comment: ok Bhanu thanks! but someone else had given more accurate answer so I have to mark tick on him.. but I'll use your logic- Date lastModified = new Date(file.lastModified());
Thank you